# OS-X (El Capitan)上のEmacsでコントロール+上下矢印キーを働かせたい

Tags: macos, emacs

タイトルの環境でEmacsを動かしているのですが、シェルモードでコントロール+上矢印キーを押すと、開いているアプリケーションのスクリーンショット一覧が出てしまいます。これ自体はOS-X本来の仕様だと思うのですが、なんとか回避して、Emacsデフォルトのキーバインドにする手段はないでしょうか。

なお、Virtualbox上にインストールしたubuntu16.04では、コントロール+上下矢印キーは期待通りの動きをしました。昨日、両方を開いて作業していたので見間違えたのだと思います。お騒がせしました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Macの言語設定は英語の前提)
`リンゴマーク > System preferences... > Keyboard`
で
`コントロール + 上矢印キー`については
ShortcutsタブからMission Control の一番上の Mission Controlのチェックを外せばよいと思います。　下記画像の右側の一番上のチェックです。

`コントロール + 下矢印キー`については
Application windowsのチェックをはずせばよいと思います。上から４つ目のチェックです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 教えていただいた方法でコントロール+上矢印キーは期待通りに動くようになりました。ただ、これだけでは、コントロール+下矢印キーは0S-Xのデフォルトの動きをするようです。これはどこを直せばいいのでしょうか。なお、Virtualbox上のubuntuの上のemacsも、時折、同じ動きをすることがあることがわかりました。再現条件はつかめていません。フォーカスが当たっていてもキーがVirtualboxに渡らないタイミングがあるようです。

Comment: @ponpoko2 追記しました。

Comment: コントロール+下矢印キーについても書いていただいてくださっていたのですね。こちらも動作を確認いたしました。

Comment: @ponpoko2  よかったです。解決した場合は、回答にチェックをお願いします。チェックがないと未解決として残ってしまいます。

Comment: Emacsに閉じた解決がないかとも思ったのですが、Virtualbox上のEmacsのことも考えると、システムの設定を変えるのが良さそうです。